# [Nodejs]How to use filter with rest connector in loopback 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, loopbackjs

- I have a model.js like this:

```
module.exports = function(Magazine) {
   let coffeeShopService = Magazine.app.dataSources.CoffeeShopService;

   let filter = {where: {id : 13}};
   let result = await  coffeeShopService.getByFilter();
};
```

and datasource.js

```
  "CoffeeShopService": {
    "name": "CoffeeShopService",
    "connector": "rest",
    "operations": [
      {
        "template": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "http://localhost:3001/api/CoffeeShops"
        },
        "functions": {
          "getByFilter": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

And I want to pass `filter` to `coffeeShopService.getByFilter();`
like when i use axios :

```
const axios = require('axios');

let url = "http://localhost:3001/api/CoffeeShops";
let filter = {where: {id: 12}};
let result = await axios.get(url, {params: {filter: filter}});
```